# Group By and Sum clauses in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've written a simple linq query as follows:

```
var query = from c in context.ViewDeliveryClientActualStatus
            join b in context.Booking on c.Booking equals b.Id
            join bg in context.BookingGoods on c.Booking equals bg.BookingId
            select new { c, b, bg };
```

I have filtered the previous query with a number of premises and then needed to group by a set of fields and get the sum of some of them, as so:

```
var rows = from a in query
           group a by new {h = a.c.BookingRefex, b = a.c.ClientRefex, c = a.b.PickupCity, d = a.b.PickupPostalCode} into g
           select new
           {                     
               Booking_refex = g.Key.h,
               Client_refex = g.Key.b,
               //Local = g.
               Sum_Quan = g.Sum(p => p.bg.Quantity),
           };
```

I'd like to get a few values from `a` which I haven't included in the group by clause. How can I get those values? They're not accessible through `g`.

Comment: I don't understand how you loose access to fields by doing groupby. In your example you are computing the sum of bg.Quantity which is not part of g.Key. Can you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: I got access to bg.Quantity through Sum but if I type g. it is not in the field properties list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `g` in your LINQ expression is an `IEnumerable` containing `a's` with an extra property `Key`. If you want to access fields of `a` that are not part of `Key` you will have to perform some sort of aggregation or selection. If you know that a particular field is the same for all elements in the group you can pick the value of the field from the first element in the group. In this example I assume that `c` has a field named `Value`:

```
var rows = from a in query
  group a by new {
    h = a.c.BookingRefex,
    b = a.c.ClientRefex,
    c = a.b.PickupCity,
    d = a.b.PickupPostalCode
  } into g
  select new { 
    BookingRefex = g.Key.h, 
    ClientRefex = g.Key.b, 
    SumQuantity = g.Sum(p => p.bg.Quantity),
    Value = g.First().c.Value
  };
```

However, if `c.Value` is the same within a group you might as well include it in the grouping and access it using `g.Key.cValue`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, right what I needed. And also learned something useful!

Answer (score 1):

Just add those field in the

```
new {h = a.c.BookingRefex, b = a.c.ClientRefex, c = a.b.PickupCity, d = a.b.PickupPostalCode}
```

they will be accessible in g then.

Comment: Does that mean I have to add every field to the list every time I do a group by? There are a lot of fields to add.

Comment: If you don't want to group by the extra fields you should not include them in the object that is used to create the groups.

Comment: By doing the instruction above you just get the elements you stated in the new {...}; see it as a t-sql SELECT statement: if you do not select * but a subset of columns the others would be unaccessible.

Comment: Okay, what I was trying to accomplish was the sum of 3 fields included in 'a' but to use Sum() I need to use the group by clause. But by doing so I lose access to the other fields in 'a' that I must output in the final query.