# LINQ - Can't add column to result without changing multi-table grouping

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Suppose I have a "database" defined as:

```
// Baked goods vendors
   var vendor = new[] {
    new { ID = 1, Baker = "Pies R Us", StMnemon = "NY", Items = 8, Rating = 9 },
    new { ID = 2, Baker = "Mikes Muffins", StMnemon = "CA", Items = 5, Rating = 9 },
    new { ID = 3, Baker = "Best Bakers", StMnemon = "FL", Items = 2, Rating = 5 },
    new { ID = 4, Baker = "Marys Baked Treats", StMnemon = "NY", Items = 8, Rating = 7 },
    new { ID = 5, Baker = "Cool Cakes", StMnemon = "NY", Items = 4, Rating = 9 },
    new { ID = 6, Baker = "Pie Heaven", StMnemon = "CA", Items = 12, Rating = 9 },
    new { ID = 7, Baker = "Cakes N More", StMnemon = "GA", Items = 6, Rating = 8 },
    new { ID = 8, Baker = "Dream Desserts", StMnemon = "FL", Items = 2, Rating = 7 }
};

// Locations
var location = new[] {
    new {ID= 1, State = "New York", Mnemonic = "NY"},
    new {ID= 2, State = "Massachusetts", Mnemonic = "MA"},
    new {ID= 3, State = "Ohio", Mnemonic = "OH"},
    new {ID= 4, State = "California", Mnemonic = "CA"},
    new {ID= 5, State = "Florida", Mnemonic = "FL"},
    new {ID= 6, State = "Texas", Mnemonic = "TX"},
    new {ID= 7, State = "Georgia", Mnemonic = "GA" }
};
```

I want to build a query that would be the equivalent of the SQL query:

```
SELECT   State, Rating, SUM(Items) AS 'Kinds'
FROM     vendor, location
WHERE    vendor.StMnemon = location.Mnemonic
GROUP BY State, Rating
```

Two things of interest in this query are:

1. The GROUP BY involves multiple tables, and
2. The result contains a summation of a column not appearing in the grouping criteria.

I've seen the solutions in the posts on [grouping by multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724719/group-multiple-tables-in-linq) and [summing columns not in the group-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092088/group-by-and-sum-clauses-in-linq).  The problem is that combining both doesn't really duplicate the relational query.

I try to duplicate it in LINQ with the following code:

```
var query = from v in vendor
           join l in location
           on v.StMnemon equals l.Mnemonic
           orderby v.Rating ascending, l.State
           select new { v, l };

var result = from q in query
           group q by new { 
               s = q.l.State, 
               r = q.v.Rating
/* ==> */    , i = q.v.Items
           } into grp
        select new 
        {
            State = grp.Key.s,
            Rating = grp.Key.r
/* ==> */ , Kinds = grp.Sum(k => grp.Key.i)
        };
```

This results in:

```
=================================
State           Rating  Kinds
Florida         5       2
Florida         7       2
New York        7       8
Georgia         8       6
California      9       5
California      9       12
New York        9       8
New York        9       4
=================================
```

Whereas, the SQL query given above gives this result:

```
=========================
State       Rating  Kinds
Florida     5       2
Florida     7       2
New York    7       8
Georgia     8       6
California  9       17
New York    9       12
=========================
```

The discrepancy is because there seems to be ***no place to put additional columns, other than in the grouping criteria***, which of course changes the grouped result.  Commenting out the two lines indicated by the **/* ==> */** comment in the code above will give the same grouping as the SQL result, but of course that removes the summation field that I want to include.

How do we group multiple tables in LINQ and include additional criteria without changing the grouped result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this seems to return the same as the SQL query:

```
var result = from v in vendor
             from l in location
             where l.Mnemonic == v.StMnemon
             group v by new { l.State, v.Rating } into grp
             orderby grp.Key.Rating ascending, grp.Key.State
             select new {State = grp.Key.State, Rating = grp.Key.Rating, Kinds = grp.Sum(p=>p.Items)};

foreach (var item in result)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", item.State, item.Rating, item.Kinds);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do an aggregation outside of the group:

```
var query = from v in vendor
           join l in location
           on v.StMnemon equals l.Mnemonic
           orderby v.Rating ascending, l.State
           select new { v, l };

var result = from q in query
           group q by new { 
               s = q.l.State, 
               r = q.v.Rating
           } into grp
        select new 
        {
            State = grp.Key.s,
            Rating = grp.Key.r,
            Kinds = grp.Sum(g => g.Items)
        };
```

Grouping is a little tricky to grasp - it returns an `IGrouping` that has one property - `Key`.  The actual items in that grouping are returned by the `GetEnumerator()` function that lets you treat the group as a collection of those items, meaning you can do aggregation on the items within that group.